# Wildcard for Excel worksheet name in Dataweave

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Mule 4 and Anypoint Studio 7.

I am processing a report in xlsx which is auto-generated and gives the worksheet an auto-generated name which means it can be different every time.  Is there a way in Dataweave to use specify a wildcard for the worksheet name when transforming the payload?  There will only be one worksheet in the workbook.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xlsx
---
{
    "Sheet 1": payload."Sheet 1" map ( sheet1 , indexOfSheet1 ) -> {
        EmployeeId: sheet1.EmployeeId default "" as String,
        Name: sheet1.Name default "" as String
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is always only one you want to select, then the simplest option is to choose it by index: [0] works on maps as well as arrays:

```
{
    "Sheet 1": payload[0] map ( sheet1 , indexOfSheet1 ) -> {
        EmployeeId: sheet1.EmployeeId default "" as String,
        Name: sheet1.Name default "" as String
    }
}
```